# How to make Intellij run the product generated by "maven package"?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'd like to know how to make Intellij run the product generated by my `maven package` instead of its default output. My `maven package` makes a couple of modifications to my jar, so its result will differ from what I'd get with a regular application launch.

Comment: What do you mean by "run?" If you mean "IntelliJ's run/debug launcher," you may have to settle for creating a Maven execution task, using exec:java as Puce suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Maven Exec Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).